# Calculate Columns Row Total in SharePoint Designer 2010 (Data Form/XSLT Web Part)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt

I am using Data Form Web Part in SharePoint Designer 2010 (or XSLT Web Part would also work):

I have a table like below:

```
ColumnA         ColumnB         Status

Project1        Task1.1         Completed

Project1        Task1.2         Pending

Project1        Task1.3         Completed

Project2        Task2.1         Completed

Project3        Task3.1         Completed

Project3        Task3.2         Completed

Project3        Task3.3         Completed

Project3        Task3.4         Pending

Project3        Task3.5         Pending
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
Project1        66.67 ((Completed Task / Total Task) * 100)

Project2        100

Project3        60
```

Comment: Guys, No answers?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done with the SPD 2010 Visual Designer, but could probably be done by hand coding some custom xslt. In my opinion however , your best bet would be to get the data to the browser using csom or rest or spservices and render it there using javascript (maybe jsrender templates). I think you need either custom XSLT or custom javascript to do this.